# Time difference between running s3 sync with and without --dryrun option

Tags: amazon-s3

Consider that I have an S3 bucket that has ~900K images in it, I wish to know if what time it would take to download them on my server from S3.

Would running sync command with --dryrun option take the same time as doing it without --dryrun? And if yes how it works - are the images downloaded but never pushed to local directory? Am I incurring cost with --dryrun as well?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would running sync command with --dryrun option take the same time as doing it without --dryrun?

No, the command with `--dryrun` will take less time to run. The `sync` command consists of "check" and "doing the actual upload/download work".

**"check"** means comparing the metadata between the local and remote objects and determining whether an object needs to be synced or not.

**"doing the actual upload/download work"** means the PUT or GET HTTP requests against S3.

Therefore, using the analogy above, you can think of

1. sync with `--dryrun` = "check"
2. sync without `--dryrun` = "check" + "doing the actual upload/download work"

You can verify what I said by using the `--debug` flag provided by AWS CLI. Here is the simplest command that I use to check this:

```
aws s3 sync --dryrun . s3://<your-bueket-name> --debug 2>&1 | grep urllib3
```

The output should only contain HTTP requests that list S3 objects in the bucket. For example,

```
2021-01-31 16:28:51,635 - MainThread - urllib3.connectionpool - DEBUG - https://<your-bueket-name>.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443 "GET /?list-type=2&prefix=&encoding-type=url HTTP/1.1" 200 None
```

If you read the [`man` page](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3/sync.html#examples) for `sync` command carefully, you will notice that the actual content of the object is not downloaded/uploaded when you execute `sync` with `--dryrun`. The `sync` utility uses the response of the list objects API to do the "check".

> The following sync command syncs objects under a specified prefix and bucket to files in a local directory by uploading the local files to s3. **A local file will require uploading if the size of the local file is different than the size of the s3 object, the last modified time of the local file is newer than the last modified time of the s3 object, or the local file does not exist under the specified bucket and prefix.** In this example, the user syncs the bucket mybucket to the local current directory. The local current directory contains the files test.txt and test2.txt. The bucket mybucket contains no objects.

To answer your follow-up questions:

> And if yes how it works - are the images downloaded but never pushed to local directory?

No.

> Am I incurring cost with --dryrun as well?

Yes, you will incur the cost of LIST requests.

Comment: Thanks @jellycsc for explaining very well.